# Foundation framework form does not refresh on new instantiation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, zurb-foundation

I have developed a form in foundation framework. It is fired through a link and loads in modal.

It is fired through

```
<a class="add-btn button right small" data-reveal-id="addModal">Add Contact</a>
```

It points to a div with `id="addModal"` in the same file.

```
<div id="addModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   <h2>Add Contact</h2>
   <form id="addContact" action="#" method="post">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="large-6 columns"><label>First Name <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" /></label></div>
     <div class="large-6 columns"><label>Last Name <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /></label></div>
   </div>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" class="add-btn button right small" value="Add Contact" />
   <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
   </form>
</div>
```

The ajax form handler is  as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('submit','#addContact',function(){
    $.post('add_contact.php',$(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#addModal').foundation('reveal','close');
            showContacts();
        });
        return false;
});
```

The php script `add_contact.php` is working fine. Everything is working fine. When I click add contact, the new record is inserted. When we click add contact again, the old values entered remains there. Which part of my code show old values and how can I clear after each form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not really posting the form, but using AJAX instead, you need to reset the form manually, using in-built [`#reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) method of the form:

```
document.addContact.reset();
```